# How to count how many bars back the moving average crossed last?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I am writing an MQL4 Custom Indicator that would tell how many bars ago a particular set of moving averages crossed.

To be specific, I want the output to show me that

> "The 20 period `MA( .. PRICE_OPEN )` is below `MA( .. PRICE_CLOSE )` for the past 10 bars".

in a form of an **`int`** number.

```
double ma1 = iMA( Symbol(), 10080, 20, 0, 0, PRICE_OPEN,  0 );
double ma2 = iMA( Symbol(), 10080, 20, 0, 0, PRICE_CLOSE, 0 );
```

I want to find out that `ma1` has been above or below `ma2` for how many bars since the current bar.

Comment: Welcome, @mmdel, you might want to correct your code, if not mentioned otherwise, so as to reflect the written specification. As far as understood your introduction, **ma1** should contain a 10-bar period Moving Average, not a 20-bar one, shan't it? **Anyway, happy trading.**

Comment: @user3666197, thanks. i actually want both 20 period ma only. the only difference is one is of the close and other is of the open.

Comment: Right. In that case, you ought correct the text part, so as to reflect this intention and become self-consistent with your question.

Comment: **Q:** in which manner you seek the  **`MQL4 output`** to be presented? In an example, you have used a textual representation -- is it correct? Kindly be specific,  **`MQL4 Custom Indicator`** algorithmisation is rather specific ( as per a code-execution model ) and restrictive ( as per the access to XTO, GUI and similar operations ).

Comment: @user3666197. My apologies. i want the output as a numeric figure. i.e an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TLDR;
```

### **`MQL4`** <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd> design is a bit schizophrenic task with 2 parts

Once decided to design a <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd>, one has to pay attention to both sides of the coin.

`MQL4` code has a non-trivial signature for a caller-side
( normally an 
<kbd>Expert Advisor</kbd> or a <kbd>Script</kbd> type of MQL4 code )
and
<kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd>, on it's own,
 operates in a special mode, where it calculates & store it's values into one or more arrays called **`IndexBuffer`**-s.

> **`Phase  I.:`** design Caller-side interface ( what all do we need to set / receive ? )
>   **`Phase II.:`** design <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd> implementation side

This way, the given indicator shall

- **set** just one parameter: a `period` ... `20`
- **receive**  just one `int` a value of days `{ +:above | 0: xoss | -: under` }

---

### `Phase  I.` `:` Design Caller-side interface

Given the above parametrisation and the `MQL4` concept of <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd> construction, the following universal template ( recommended to be routinely maintained as a commented section right in `CustomIndicator`-file ) reflects details needed for the Caller-side interface ( which one benefits from by just a copy-paste mechanics, while the implementation-integrity responsibility is born by the `CustomIndicator` maintainer ):

```
// CALL-er SIDE INTERFACE |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
                                                // 
                                                // #define sIndicatorPathNAME             "#AliceInTheWonderlands_msMOD_0.00"
                                                // 
                                                // //_____________________________________INPUT(s)
                                                // // iMA_PERIOD:
                                                // extern int   iMA_PERIOD    = 20;
                                                // 
                                                // //_____________________________________OUTPUT(s):
                                                // #define iOutputDoubleUpOrDnBUFFER     0
                                                // 
                                                // //_____________________________________CALL-SIGNATURE:
                                                // 
                                                //                            double  iCustom(  _Symbol,                      // string       symbol,           // symbol:                                                 Symbol name on the data of which the indicator will be calculated. NULL means the current symbol.
                                                //                                              PERIOD_W1,                    // int          timeframe,        // timeframe
                                                //                                              sIndicatorPathNAME,           // string       name,             // path/name of the custom indicator compiled program:     Custom indicator compiled program name, relative to the root indicators directory (MQL4/Indicators/). If the indicator is located in subdirectory, for example, in MQL4/Indicators/Examples, its name must be specified as "Examples\\indicator_name" (double backslash "\\"must be specified as separator instead of a single one).
                                                //                                              iMA_PERIOD,                   // ...[1]       ...,              // custom indicator [1]-st input parameter
                                                //                                              <<N/A>>,                      // ...[2+]                        // custom indicator further input parameters (if necessary)
                                                //                                              iOutputDoubleUpOrDnBUFFER,    // int          mode,             // line index:                                             Line index. Can be from 0 to 7 and must correspond with the index, specified in call of the SetIndexBuffer() function.
                                                //                                              i                             // int          bar_shift         // shift
                                                //                                              );
                                                // ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Typical <kbd>Expert Advisor</kbd> call looks like this:

```
int anIndicatorVALUE = iCustom( _Symbol,
                                PERIOD_W1,
                                sIndicatorPathNAME,
                                iMA_PERIOD,
                                iOutputDoubleUpOrDnBUFFER,
                                aCurrentBarPTR
                                );
if ( 0 > anIndicatorVALUE ) // on "line" under for <anIndicatorVALUE> [PERIOD]-s
{ ...
}
```

---

### `Phase II.` `:` Design <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd> implementation side

**Preset** an overall capacity

```
#property indicator_buffers 1            // compile time directive
```

**Allocate** memory for `IndexBuffer`(s) needed

```
IndicatorBuffers( 1 );                   // upper limit of 512 is "far" enough
```

**Declare** `IndexBuffer`

```
double UpOrDnBUFFER[];                   // mandatory to be a double
```

**Associate** `IndexBuffer` with an index

```
SetIndexBuffer( 0, UpOrDnBUFFER );       // index 0: UpOrDnBUFFER[]
ArraySetAsSeries(  UpOrDnBUFFER, True ); // reverse AFTER association
```

The core logic of any <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd> is inside an **`OnCalculate()`** function, where you
- **implement** desired calculus
and
- **store** resulting values into respective cells of the **`UpOrDnBUFFER[];`**

Writing a fully fledged code upon request is not the key objective of StackOverflow, but let me sketch a few notes on this, as  <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd> implementation side requires a bit practice:

- because <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd> `OnCalculate()` operates "progressively", so do design your calculation strategy & keep in mind the state-less-ness between "blocks" of forward-progressive blocks of calculations.
- as given, crosses are tri-state system, so watch issues on cases, where decisions are made on a "live" bar, where the state { `above` | `cross` | `under` } may change many times during the bar-evolution.